# How to send PDF from one lambda to the other?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to send a PDF file that's in an S3 bucket from one lambda to a second. For that, I am downloading the PDF in the `tmp` folder from the S3 bucket and then invoking the second lambda.

My codes:

```
s3r = boto3.resource('s3')
client = boto3.client('lambda')
s3r.meta.client.download_file(
    Bucket='my_bucket',
    Key='pdf_folder' + '/{}'.format(pdf_name),
    Filename='/tmp/'+pdf_name
)
```

I then try to invoke the second lambda and send the PDF as a payload as follows:

```
client.invoke(
    FunctionName='second_lambda',
    InvocationType="RequestResponse",
    Payload={
        'pdf': '/tmp/'+pdf_name,
        'email': receiver_email,
    }
)
```

But I get the following error:

> botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
> Invalid type for parameter Payload, value: {'pdf':
> '/tmp/test_pdf_ff9cf3167ae6fc1552f340a7abc529970fb8cf5a65f8bc825d772fa5e707c81d.pdf',
> 'email': receiver_email}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class
> 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object

What's the mistake I am doing?

Comment: Why cant lambda #2 read the pdf from s3?

Comment: @balderman That was the initial thought, but I am trying to make lambda #2 as generalized as possible, in case the pdf isn't in the S3 bucket. There are other functionalities connected, that's why it makes sense to send the pdf from #1 to  #2

Comment: pdfs can be large. Are you confident that you will never hit limits of payload size?

Comment: @Marcin  Can you please tell me what's the max payload limit? Is it 6MB for sync and 256KB for async?

Comment: @Junkrat yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Marcin Each PDF is like 100kb and each time I just want to send one PDF and not a bunch of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Payload` can only be "bytes or seekable file-like object". However you have a dictionary.

To provide file-like object, you can do:

```
with open('/tmp/'+pdf_name, 'rb') as f:
   client.invoke(
      FunctionName='second_lambda',
      InvocationType="RequestResponse",
      Payload=f
  )
```

Update:

You can encode your file as `base64`, put into `dict`, then make dict into `json` and then into `bytes` :

```
import base64
import json

with open('/tmp/'+pdf_name, 'rb') as f:
   client.invoke(
      FunctionName='second_lambda',
      InvocationType="RequestResponse",
      Payload=json.dumps({
        'pdf': base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode("ascii"),
        'email': receiver_email,
    }).encode()
  )
```

Or with `pickle`:

```
import pickle

with open('/tmp/'+pdf_name, 'rb') as f:
   client.invoke(
      FunctionName='second_lambda',
      InvocationType="RequestResponse",
      Payload=pickle.dumps({
        'pdf': f.read(),
        'email': receiver_email,
    })
  )
```

Comment: I also have to send `email` as a part of the payload along with the PDF.  As you see in the payload in the `invoke` part of the code. Any suggestion for combining both?

Comment: @Junkrat I updated the question with new way. Obviously the receiving function has to reverse the procedure.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try and then accept the answer

Comment: @Junkrat I added pickle version.

Comment: Hey, one question: after encoding it with  `base64.b64encode(f.read())` why did you add `.decode("ascii")` ?

Comment: @Junkrat Base64 will produce bytes, which will not work with json.dumps. Encode changes these bytes to string.